# Use -notlike to filter out multiple strings in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to read the event log for a security audit for all users except two, but is it possible to do that with the `-notlike` operator?

It's something like that:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | where {$_.UserName -notlike @("*user1","*user2")}
```

I have it working for a single user, like:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | where {$_.UserName -notlike "*user1"}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

V2 at least contains the `-username` parameter that takes a string[], and supports globbing.

V1 you want to expand your test like so:

```
Get-EventLog Security | ?{$_.UserName -notlike "user1" -and $_.UserName -notlike "*user2"}
```

Or you could use "-notcontains" on the inline array but this would only work if you can do exact matching on the usernames.

`... | ?{@("user1","user2") -notcontains $_.username}`

Comment: You can also reference the list of usernames to filter out via a variable:  ?{$users -notcontains $_.username}

Answer (score 16):

I think Peter has the right idea.  I would use a regular expression for this along with the -notmatch operator.

```
Get-EventLog Security | ?{$_.Username -notmatch '^user1$|^.*user$'}
```

Answer (score 8):

In order to support "matches any of ..." scenarios, I created a function that is pretty easy to read. My version has a lot more to it because its a PowerShell 2.0 cmdlet but the version I'm pasting below should work in 1.0 and has no frills.

You call it like so:

```
Get-Process | Where-Match Company -Like '*VMWare*','*Microsoft*'
Get-Process | Where-Match Company -Regex '^Microsoft.*'

filter Where-Match($Selector,[String[]]$Like,[String[]]$Regex) {

    if ($Selector -is [String]) { $Value = $_.$Selector }
    elseif ($Selector -is [ScriptBlock]) { $Value = &$Selector }
    else { throw 'Selector must be a ScriptBlock or property name' }

    if ($Like.Length) {
        foreach ($Pattern in $Like) {
            if ($Value -like $Pattern) { return $_ }
        }
    }

    if ($Regex.Length) {
        foreach ($Pattern in $Regex) {
            if ($Value -match $Pattern) { return $_ }
        }
    }

}

filter Where-NotMatch($Selector,[String[]]$Like,[String[]]$Regex) {

    if ($Selector -is [String]) { $Value = $_.$Selector }
    elseif ($Selector -is [ScriptBlock]) { $Value = &$Selector }
    else { throw 'Selector must be a ScriptBlock or property name' }

    if ($Like.Length) {
        foreach ($Pattern in $Like) {
            if ($Value -like $Pattern) { return }
        }
    }

    if ($Regex.Length) {
        foreach ($Pattern in $Regex) {
            if ($Value -match $Pattern) { return }
        }
    }

    return $_

}
```

Answer (score 6):

don't use -notLike, -notMatch with Regular-Expression works in one line:

```
Get-MailBoxPermission -id newsletter | ? {$_.User -NotMatch "NT-AUTORIT.*|.*-Admins|.*Administrators|.*Manage.*"}
```

Comment: I'm curious, what is the purpose of the '.'s in this example?

Comment: A one-liner FTW.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way I find for multiple searches is to pipe them all (probably heavier CPU use) but for your example user:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | where {$_.UserName -notlike "*user1"} |  where {$_.UserName -notlike "*user2"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Scenario:
List all computers beginning with XX1 but not names where 4th character is L or P

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(name -like "XX1*")} | Select Name | Where {($_.name -notlike "XX1L*" -and $_.name -notlike "XX1P*")}
```

You can also count them by enclosing the above script in parens and adding a .count method like so:

```
(Get-ADComputer -Filter {(name -like "XX1*")} | Select Name | Where {($_.name -notlike "XX1L*" -and $_.name -notlike "XX1P*")}).count
```

Answer (score 1):

Using select-string:

```
Get-EventLog Security | where {$_.UserName | select-string -notmatch user1,user2}
```

Comment: Since the code in the question filters names that _end with_ `user1` or `user2` (`-notlike @("*user1","*user2")`), for `-Pattern` this should pass `user1$,user2$` or, more concisely, `user[12]$`.  Otherwise, this will exclude names like `user123`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$listOfUsernames = @("user1", "user2", "etc", "and so on")
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | 
    where { $_.Username -notmatch (
        '(' + [string]::Join(')|(', $listOfUsernames) + ')') }
```

It's a little crazy I'll grant you, and it fails to escape the usernames (in the unprobable case a username uses a Regex escape character like '\' or '(' ), but it works.

As "slipsec" mentioned above, use -notcontains if possible.

Comment: Thanks Peter.. That's also a great alternative!