# Powershell - LIKE against an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, sql-like

For every file being processed, its name is being checked to satisfy the condition. For example, given the following list of filters:

```
$excludeFiles = @"
aaa.bbb
ccccc.*
ddddd???.exe
"@ | SplitAndTrim;
```

It should exclude a file from processing if it matches any of the lines. Trying to avoid `match/regex`, because this script needs to be modifiable by someone who does not know it, and there are several places where it needs to implemented.

`$excludedFiles` and similar are defined as a here-string on purpose. It allows the end user/operator to paste a bunch of file names right from the CMD/Powershell window.

It appears that Powershell does not accept `-like` against an array, so I cannot write like this:

```
"ddddd000.exe" -like @("aaa.bbb", "ccccc.*", "ddddd???.exe")
```

Did I miss an option? If it's not natively supported by Powershell, what's the easiest way to implement it?

Comment: See answer from Josh Einstein: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848859/use-notlike-to-filter-out-multiple-strings-in-powershell

Comment: Thanks, @dugas, but I don't see why those complications - compare to the two lines below - see my accepted answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can perform a pattern match against a collection of names, but not against a list of patterns. Try this:

```
foreach($pattern in $excludeFiles)
{
    if($fileName -like $pattern) {break}
}
```

Here is how it can be wrapped into a function:

```
function like($str,$patterns){
    foreach($pattern in $patterns) { if($str -like $pattern) { return $true; } }
    return $false;
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought at first... just don't like the idea of having to implement this loop every time I need this functionality. I will accept this answer, if nobody else provides an alternative.

Comment: Wrap it in a function and reuse it :)

Comment: That's exactly what I did - I also updated your answer to include my solution.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a short version of the pattern in the accepted answer:

```
($your_array | %{"your_string" -like $_}) -contains $true
```

Applied to the case in the OP one obtains

```
PS C:\> ("aaa.bbb", "ccccc.*", "ddddd???.exe" | %{"ddddd000.exe" -like $_}) -contains $true
True
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could use the `Get-ChildItem` `-Exclude` parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem $theFileToCheck -exclude $excludeFiles
```

If you have an array of files to check, `Get-ChildItem` accepts an array of paths:

```
Get-ChildItem $filesToCheck -exclude $excludeFiles
```

Comment: Thanks - I can confirm that `Get-ChildItem` or simply `dir` (I am more used to Windows terminology) correctly excludes by the same pattern as LIKE, and it works for an array of strings, which can be very convenient for many uses. Unfortunately, it does not work for my needs, because in some cases I need to work with strings directly, not file objects. Still, your answer deserves a +1.

Answer (score 1):

$excludeFiles.Where{$stringToTest -like $_}

Powershell array has a Where method that can take an expression input, hence the {} instead of (). Feed in a string to test and it will iterate over the array using the standard pipe so $_ represents the element of the array.

Outputs a list of matching elements.

```
PS H:\> $excludeFiles = @("aaa.bbb", "ccccc.*", "ddddd???.exe")
PS H:\> $stringToTest = "ddddd000.exe"
PS H:\> $excludeFiles.Where{$stringToTest -like $_}
ddddd???.exe
```