# Prioritize -Exclude over -Include in Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

I am trying to sanitize my source code into another folder using Powershell:

```
dir $sourceDir\* -Recurse -Exclude */bin/*,*/obj/* -Include *.sln, *.myapp, *.vb, *.resx, *.settings, *.vbproj, *.ico, *.xml
```

And it seems like everything is working fine, however, `-Include` directive sort of whitelists the file before `-Exclude`, so `.XML` files under `/bin/`, for example, are included. I would like `-Exclude` to take precedence over `-Include`, so always exclude `/bin/` and `/obj/` folders in the above script.

It is possible in Powershell, without writing too much code?

Comment: Does the behavior change if you put your exclude items in quotes?, i.e. `-Exclude "*/bin/*", "*/obj/*"`

Comment: @David: Nope, it's the same. I refactored into using an array of values, where I included quotes (it does not work otherwise), but that did not help resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch to late filtering to exclude the directories you don't want:

```
dir $sourceDir\* -Recurse  -Include *.sln, *.myapp, *.vb, *.resx, *.settings, *.vbproj, *.ico, *.xml |
 where {$_.fullname -notmatch '\\bin\\|\\obj\\'}
```

Using -like instead of -match:

```
dir $sourceDir\* -Recurse  -Include *.sln, *.myapp, *.vb, *.resx, *.settings, *.vbproj, *.ico, *.xml |
 where { ($_.fullname -notlike '*\bin\*') -and ($_.fullname -notlike '*\obj\*') }
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid regex, i.e. keep using file system masks (`*` and `?`)?

Comment: You can also use -like instead of -match.  That will use wildcard matching instead of regex.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes, I optimized like pattern usage into more or less manageable code piece. See my answer. +1 for your efforts.

Comment: With how popular this question is, it is unlikely that more answers will appear. I will be accepting yours then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it:

```
param(
  $sourceDir="x:\Source",
  $targetDir="x:\Target"
)

function like($str,$patterns){
  foreach($pattern in $patterns) { if($str -like $pattern) { return $true; } }
  return $false;
}

$exclude = @(
"*\bin\*",
"*\obj\*"
);

$include = @(
"*.sln",
"*.myapp",
"*.vb",
"*.resx",
"*.settings",
"*.vbproj",
"*.ico",
"*.xml"
);

dir $sourceDir\* -Recurse -Include $include | where {
  !(like $_.fullname $exclude)
}
```

May not be very Powershell-ish, but it works. I used [**like function from here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019218/powershell-like-against-an-array).

Any shorter answers are welcome - please go ahead and suggest an alternative.