# Using arrays with where-object to filter multiple strings out of a csv

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables, import-csv

I am trying to filter out lines out of a csv that contain any of the values in an array.

Using this post as reference:
[Use -notlike to filter out multiple strings in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848859/use-notlike-to-filter-out-multiple-strings-in-powershell)

I managed to get it working with this format:

```
Import-Csv "$LocalPath\Stripped1Acct$abbrMonth$Year.csv" | 
    where {$_."SubmitterName" -notlike "*${Report2a}*" 
      -and $_."SubmitterName" -notlike "*${Report2b}*" 
      -and $_."SubmitterName" -notlike "*${Report2c}*"} |
    Export-Csv "$LocalPath\Stripped2Acct$abbrMonth$Year.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Eventually I plan to rewrite the script so it will pull the exclusion list from a text file generated by an end user. In order to do that, I'll have to have it access values in an array. I tried doing that with the following syntax, but it didn't work as intended:

```
Import-Csv "$LocalPath\Stripped1Acct$abbrMonth$Year.csv" | 
    where {$_."SubmitterName" -notlike "*${Report2[0]}*" 
      -and $_."SubmitterName" -notlike "*${Report2[1]}*" 
      -and $_."SubmitterName" -notlike "*${Report2[2]}*"} |
    Export-Csv "$LocalPath\Stripped2Acct$abbrMonth$Year.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I have a feeling it's just an syntax issue, but after playing around with it for far too long, I've run out of ideas.
I have a feeling it's a syntax issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a syntax issue. The `${Name}` syntax is used primarily for names that contain odd characters, like `${A ~*Strange*~ Variable Name}`. It's not an expression though, so you can't index into it with `[0]` inside the braces; that would be taken as a literal part of the variable name.

Instead you can use a sub-expression `$(...)` to do this:

```
"*$($Report2[0])*"
```

As an alternative approach, I might convert your whole array into a single regular expression and then use the `-match` (or `-notmatch`) operator:

```
$regex = $Report2.ForEach({ [RegEx]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

Import-Csv "$LocalPath\Stripped1Acct$abbrMonth$Year.csv" | 
    where {$_."SubmitterName" -notmatch $regex} |
    Export-Csv "$LocalPath\Stripped2Acct$abbrMonth$Year.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This takes the `$Report2` array, then builds an array of the same values, but escaped for Regular Expressions (so that any special characters are matched literally), and then builds a regex that looks like:

```
Item1|Item2|Item3
```

In RegEx, a pipe is alternation, so it looks for a match of `Item1` *or* `Item2`, etc. Regex finds it anywhere in the string so it doesn't need a wildcard character the way that `-like` does.

So with that built to pre-contain all items in your array, then you can use `-notmatch` to achieve the same thing, and you don't have to hardcode a bunch of indices.

Comment: If the items were simple strings using `-contains` / `-in` against the array of possibilities would work as well without the overhead (and in some cases headache) of regex. Perfect solution regardless though.

Comment: Assuming of course the string were not partials of course.

Comment: Agreed @Matt, I'm definitely a fan of `-in` and `-contains` but it seems like that wasn't the case here. Regex is pretty fast though, especially for simple compares like this.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? I'm happy to address any questions or concerns.

Comment: Not sure why he did, You answered my question and gave a more efficient way to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use contains too like this

short version

```
[string[]]$listexludevalue=Get-Content "C:\temp\exludevalue.txt"
Import-Csv "$LocalPath\Stripped1Acct$abbrMonth$Year.csv" | %{$valcontain=$true; $col=$_.Owner; $listexludevalue.ForEach({$valcontain=$valcontain -and !$col.Contains($valuetotest)}); if ($valcontain) {$_} } | Export-Csv "$LocalPath\Stripped2Acct$abbrMonth$Year.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

detailed version :

```
$listexludevalue=Get-Content "C:\temp\exludevalue.txt"

Import-Csv "$LocalPath\Stripped1Acct$abbrMonth$Year.csv" | 
% {

    $valcontain=$true

    foreach ($valuetotest in $listexludevalue) {$valcontain=$valcontain -and !$_.SubmitterName.Contains($valuetotest)}

    if ($valcontain) {$_}

   } | Export-Csv "$LocalPath\Stripped2Acct$abbrMonth$Year.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: -contains not, but variable.contains yes

Comment: contains work with dynamic content when you use like this, give an example of your affirmation please

Comment: @Esperento57 What I mean was what do you do when the source file has 5 lines? Your code currently does not work.

Comment: Ok you'r right, ty Matt. I have modified my code ;)