# powershell function to exclude names in csv

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powercli

I have the following script i which i am trying to shutdown all the guests with a cluster except for those listed in the csv. In the below code i have put "select name" over "stop-vmguest" so that i can test without breaking anything. Currently it is ignoring the csv and just outputting the name of every server in the cluster so would just be powering everything off..

```
$exclusion = get-content "C:\scripts\input\vmExclusion.csv"

$vms = get-cluster "mycluster" | get-vm

Foreach($vm in $vms){

$vm | Where-object {$_.name -notlike $esxclusion.Name }  | select name

}
```

Comment: Use `-notin` rather than `-notlike`

Comment: thanks but that does the same just outputs everything. I also noticed in my troubleshooting if i were to foreach ($name in $exculusion) {write-host $name.name} it returns a blank space where the names should be so i wondered if there was something wrong with the input

Comment: If `vmExclusion.csv` has a `Name` header, then use `Import-Csv` rather than `Get-Content`. Then `$exclusion.Name` will work.

Comment: You do realize that you've spelled the variable name wrong. You get content into `$exclusion` and look for `$esxclusion`.

Answer (score 0):

Use -notlike instead of -notin
ref - [Use -notlike to filter out multiple strings in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848859/use-notlike-to-filter-out-multiple-strings-in-powershell), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 0):

The `-notlike` [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7) is used for comparing a string to a string. It does offer the ability to do simple wildcard matching. However, when comparing a string to a collection or collection to a string, `-notin` and `-notcontains`, respectively, make the job easier.

```
$SingleString -notin $ArrayOfStrings
$ArrayOfStrings -notcontains $SingleString
```

If for whatever reason, you need to compare a string to a collection while using wildcards, you can use `-notmatch`. This operator uses regex matching, which relies on its own language of pattern matching syntax. The example below compares the `$SingleString` value to each value in `$ArrayOfStrings` with surrounding wildcards like `*value1*`,`*value2*`, etc.

```
$Regex = ($ArrayOfStrings |% {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
$SingleString -notmatch $Regex
```

---

For reading contents as objects with custom properties, [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) makes life easier. If your file contains a header row (first line of delimited property names), you can simply use the command with matching delimiter. Your session will have a default delimiter based on your culture settings. On my system, that is a `,`. If your file contains only data, you can add a `-Header` parameter to act as the property set.

```
# If the file contains a header row
$exclusion = Import-Csv "C:\scripts\input\vmExclusion.csv"

# If file contains one column of text without a header row
$exclusion = Import-Csv "C:\scripts\input\vmExclusion.csv" -Header Name

# outputs all Name property values from the file
$exclusion.Name

# outputs the first Name property value only
$exclusion[0].Name

# loops over each data row in the csv
$exclusion | Foreach-Object {
    $_ # Current data row as the loop iterates
    $_.Name # Current Name property value
}
```

---

`Select` is an alias for [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7). Using `Select-Object` without the `-ExpandProperty` parameter will return a custom object with properties. Using `-ExpandProperty` returns just the value of a single property.

```
# returns a custom object with only the Name property
$vm | Where-object {$_.name -notin $exclusion.Name }  | Select Name

# returns the value of the Name property
$vm | Where-object {$_.name -notin $exclusion.Name }  | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, i have tried -notlike -notmatch -notcontains -notin etc and all seem to be reporting the contents of the cluster still. The import-csv was a school boy thanks for pointing that out cant believe i missed that. I also tried the regex suggestion and the doesnt make any difference

Comment: ```
$exclusion = Import-Csv "C:\scripts\input\vmExclusion.csv"

$vms = get-cluster "ESMDRCLS-Prod01" | get-vm

Foreach($vm in $vms){


$Regex = ($exclusion |% {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'

$vm | Where-object {$_.name -notmatch $regex }  | select name
}
```

Comment: Does `vmExclusion.csv` have a first value of Name at the top?

Comment: If `vmExclusion.csv` contains `Name` as its first value, then you must use `$exclusion.Name` when joining the values. If the file does not contain `Name` at the top, then use `Import-Csv vmExclusion.csv -Header Name`. You will still need to use `$exclusion.Name` to reference any value as a scalar.

Comment: The csv does have the header of Name at the top yes

Comment: if the file contains the exact vm names, then it should work easily with `-notin` provided you spell `$exclusion` correctly in your `where-object`.